# uibutton does not change the image for expand-collapse feature in uitableview objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement expand - collapse feature in `UITableview`.

1) section 1 :
    contain 2 rows

2) section 2:
    contain 3 rows

1) section 3 :
    contain 2 rows

2) section 4:
    contain 2 rows

- Section have `UILabel` and `UIButton` in their view.
  `UIButton` have image of + and -
  when user click on "+" button that section got expand and display the rows and the other section get collapse
  and the image of the button change to "-"

  When user click on "-" button in section. The section got collpase and image of button change to "+"

But problem is when i click on "+" button and reload the `UITableview` the image of the button dont get change.
please help me the solution and proper way to implement expand and collapse row.

```
  - (IBAction)BtnSection_ExpandCollapseAction:(UIButton *)sender {
        sectionselected = sender.tag;   // remember which section is tapped
        if(sender.selected){
            Isopen = FALSE;   // whether to expand or to collapse
            sender.selected = false;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnPlus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }else{
            Isopen = TRUE;
            sender.selected = TRUE;
            [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnMinus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        [self.tblView reloadData];
    }

    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        UIView *HeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, self.view.frame.size.width-10, 35)];
        HeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

        UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-80, 5, 50, HeaderView.frame.size.height-10)];
        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnPlus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(BtnSection_ExpandCollapseAction:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        btn.tag = section;
        UILabel *LblHeader = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 5,HeaderView.frame.size.width-10, HeaderView.frame.size.height-10)];
        if(section == 0){
            LblHeader.text = @"Chief Compalain";
        }else if(section == 1){
            LblHeader.text = @"Extra Oral";
        }else if(section == 2){
            LblHeader.text = @"Intra Oral";
        }else if(section == 3){
            LblHeader.text = @"Radiographical";
        }
        LblHeader.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [HeaderView addSubview:LblHeader];

        [HeaderView addSubview:btn];

        return HeaderView;
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        if(Isopen){
            if(section == sectionselected){
                return 7;
            }else{
                return 0;
            }
        }else{
            return 0;
        }

    }


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

for reference check image 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is because after you set the image you reload the table view. If you was to not reload the table view after setting the button image you would see that the image would in fact change.

**Why does reloading the TableView cause the image to change back?**

This is because the button is then reinitialized in your `viewForHeaderInSection` method which turns it back to a plus.

The code that does this is here:

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-80, 5, 50, HeaderView.frame.size.height-10)];

[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnPlus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**How do I fix this?**

When the button is selected the action should change a property on the datasource object so you know its open for example a property called `isOpen`. so when the button is pressed you want `section.isOpen` to be true. Then reload the table view.

Now the magic will happen in `viewForHeaderInSection`. You need to add an if statement there.

```
if (section.isOpen == true)
{
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnMinus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else
{
    [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BtnPlus"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: in swift : put this code in viewForHeaderInSection :::->

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

 if data[section].isExpandable
        {
           btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_faq_detail_hide"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }else{
            btn.setImage(UIImage(named: "ic_view_details"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
        }}